# Pitfalls to having __eq__ raise an exception?

Tags: python, equality

I have a type where equality comparison doesn't make sense. Explicitly comparing two instances of this type for either reference or value equality would indicate a logic error in the calling code.

Is it bad to define `__eq__` to raise an exception? Are there pitfalls to this? Is it implicitly called as a part of some common operation?

In a language like Haskell I would simply not implement the Equal typeclass, and attempting the comparison would be a compile error. Since python is completely dynamic, do I have an option that would help encourage correct usage if this definition isn't a good idea?

I could `return NotImplemented`, but then it does fallback comparisons that will ultimately result in an identity comparison if the RHS also returns `NotImplemented`, and I still don't want that.

Comment: Without reference to your code, it sounds like you're abusing the `==` operator, and should be using a different operator or a function instead.

Comment: @Dunes That's the point, I want to make sure `==` is not used.

Comment: The pythonic answer is to document usage, but if user insist on using == then let them.

Comment: @Dunes You could post that as an answer

Comment: I am sincerely curious what sort of thing you have created where reference equality doesn't make sense.  I understand why a type might not be value-comparable, but why is reference equality a problem?  What sort of error would result from the calling code doing `a is b`?  (This isn't a criticism, I want to learn something here?)

Comment: @IanMcLaird `a is b` is fine, and it wouldn't be a problem, it's just not useful. The problem is that if you do not define `__eq__`, then python performs reference checking - this means I have to implement something or I'm in no better position that implementing it in terms of `return False` or something like that. My goal is to make it clear that this class's user should do something completely different.

Comment: Pretty sure making `__eq__` throw will prevent your class from being used as keys in a dictionary. Dictionaries are a common way to "attach" arbitrary values to reference-comparable objects.

Comment: @doublep That would be a great answer regarding pitfalls of this approach.

Comment: @Daenyth Is it possible to know the actual use case? I too am really interested where you need this.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen In a nutshell, these objects are components to a larger item, and can only be compared in the context of that larger item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making `__eq__` throw will prevent your class from being used as keys in a dictionary. Dictionaries are a common way to "attach" arbitrary values to reference-comparable objects.

For example:

```
class NotComparableAtAll:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        raise ValueError ('haha')

cache = { }
x, y = NotComparableAtAll (), NotComparableAtAll ()

cache[x] = 1
cache[y] = 2
```

This fails, saying that the type is not hashable.

However, if you do add `__hash__` to the class (default is removed as soon as you define `__eq__`), the example *appears* to work fine almost all the time, only it can unpredictably fail if two distinct objects turn out to have the same hash on some machine. To reproduce it, define `__hash__` to always return 0 (which does conform to `__hash__` requirements).

Additionally, overriding `__eq__` like that breaks some standard functions where comparison by reference would be useful:

```
my_list = [x, y]
my_list.remove (y)
```

This can of course be deemed another case of "these objects must really not be compared", but I guess one could come up with other similar examples where comparison is somehow nested inside a different useful operation.

Comment: Sorry, but I added `__hash__` and it did work. It didn't give any exception or problem adding a value pair to the `cache` dictionary. (At least for the first key :P)

Comment: @KurzedMetal: You are right, see the edit. It is in some sense even worse: it appears to work fine, only it can suddenly break down under rare unreproducible circumstances.

Comment: The reason why this is a bad idea is because: immutable objects should always be comparable by value, and for mutable objects there's no reason to break reference equality (why an object wouldn't be equal with itself?)

Comment: This is a big enough reason to avoid all thought of doing it; I'll have to just rely on documentation. Even though my use case wouldn't trigger this, breaking dict hashes means you can't have a set of these either.